# How to differentiate between web elements that contain the same class

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to make a list of elements that contain all the elements from these web elements:

```
<div class="league-item-block" id="LeagueId_(here there is a different id for every web element)" data-bind="css: { 'Hidden': $data.IsHidden() }, attr: { id: league.getDomId() }"></div>
```

and I use the syntax:

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("league-item-block")
```

The problem is that also have the web elements:

```
<div class="league-item-block Hidden" id="LeagueId_(here there is a different id for every web element)" data-bind="css: { 'Hidden': $data.IsHidden() }, attr: { id: league.getDomId() }"></div>
```

The list that is created contains these elements, and I do not know how to avoid them.

Comment: Use a Css selector and exclude the unwanted class: `.league-item-block:not(.Hidden)`

Comment: @Florent B.   indeed you suggestion did the job, if you write an answer i will accept it, else i will accept Ratmir's  answer that is saying the same thing

Comment: @MihaiMoldovan, you can also use `list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='league-item-block']")` to match element by exact class name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can solve your problem -- CSS Selector:

```
.league-item-block:not(.Hidden)
```

Code:

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".league-item-block:not(.Hidden)")
```